# Hadoop program compile without hadoop install

Tags: hadoop

How can I compile an hadoop example program(ex. word count) without hadoop install?

I am planning to run my program on Amazon EMR, so I don't need to run my program on my local machine.

Comment: Just the same way you compile *any* Java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the hadoop and map reduce client jar to your class path.

For example, these two should get the wordcount example to compile

> hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
>
> hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar

`hadoop-common` has the `org.apache.hadoop.io` package you'll need for your `XxxWritable, Text` classes and such. `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` has the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` you'll need for your map reduce program (Mapper, Reducer) and some basic classes for your job. I've never used Amazon EMR so I don't know how it works, and don't know if you need other jars packaged or not (or if you need an specific version). But these will get a simple map reduce program to compile.

If you're using maven, you can get these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```